# System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I'm using dual operating system for 2 weeks: Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

But today I can not boot into Windows. It says

```
System BootOrder not found. 
Initializing defaults.
```

then boots into Ubuntu directly.

`efibootmgr -v` shows this:

```
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0004,2003,2001,2002
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,55b5f8e4-699a-11e3-8f88-0c54a5f08ef1,0x200800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* UEFI: Network Card    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(202564891d67,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)..BO
Boot0002* UEFI: Network Card    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(202564891d67,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)..BO
Boot0003* UEFI: TOSHIBA MQ01ABD075  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x2)/Sata(4,65535,0)/HD(2,GPT,55b5f8e4-699a-11e3-8f88-0c54a5f08ef1,0x200800,0x32000)..BO
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,55b5f8e4-699a-11e3-8f88-0c54a5f08ef1,0x200800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
```

What should I do? I have to have access to my Windows partition. I've been searching for a solution for hours.

Comment: Logged into Ubuntu  `sudo update-grub` may fix the problem. If not, try to download, install and use boot-repair: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to terminal:

```
$ sudo su
# cd /boot/efi/EFI
# mv BOOT BOOT_back
# cp -R ubuntu BOOT
# cd BOOT
# mv shimx64.efi bootx64.efi
```

I found this on some other forums. Basically, you are replacing your boot folder with the contents of the ubuntu folder.

I do not understand enough about Ubuntu/Linux distros to understand why this works, but it has solved the issue.